# Change navigation key on website

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to change navigation key from 'Tab' to  any other on web site, for example, to 'Enter', so I could press 'Enter' and element with next 'tabindex' focused?

Comment: Are you asking about something you are developing, or changing your browser behavior as an end user?

Comment: Yes, I want that all people who visit my webapp can use this

Comment: I would recommend against this.  Don't change default browser behavior that users and screen readers have come to rely on.  You will make your site less usable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the interaction you want when you press enter (keycode 13), for example:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        alert('Enter key pressed');
        $("#element-id").focus();
    }
});
```

Alert when enter is pressed and then move focus to the item that you want

Comment: This cannot help me, I am using vue js, jquery focus() function is not working on vue components, but when I press 'Tab', the next component is selected successfully

Comment: Ok, you need to control that behavior and using the same function as above if keyCode is tab (keyCode 9) event.preventDefault(); (disable current behavior that goes to next element)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it using vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    moveNext(e) {
      let newTabIndex = +(e.target.getAttribute("tabindex") || "0") + 1;
      if (newTabIndex > this.$el.querySelectorAll("[tabindex]").length) newTabIndex = 1;
      this.$el.querySelector("[tabindex='" + newTabIndex + "']").focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" @keydown.enter.prevent="moveNext" placeholder="hit tab or enter"><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2" @keydown.enter.prevent="moveNext" placeholder="hit tab or enter"><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="3" @keydown.enter.prevent="moveNext" placeholder="hit tab or enter"><br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="4" @keydown.enter.prevent="moveNext" placeholder="hit enter"><br>
    
    <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" /> <!-- to prove .prevent is needed -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you give it a try?